# Saving .mp4 video using opencv doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save the processed frames into a video.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("video.avi", fourcc, 5, (W, H), True)
```

The above code works perfectly fine. But when I try to save it as an Mp4 with different codecs, it doesn't work. I don't get any error in the python IDE. But I just cannot play the saved .m4 file. For example

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"x264")
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("video.mp4", fourcc, 5, (W, H), True)
```

I tried (*"h264") and (*"mp4v") also. I can play other .mp4 videos in my computer except the .mp4 files saved from the above code. Should I install anything else to make the code work.

Comment: Using this video.avi will not work. Only video.mp4 will do.

Comment: what size has created file? Do you save new file with the same size as original file? If original frame has different size then `(W, H)` then you have to resize `frame` before writing.

Comment: some codecs may not work with some extensions ("containers"). `cv` uses `ffmpeg` for writing file - so all may depends on ffmpeg settings or compilation.

Comment: @toyota Supra ....sorry edied the question from video.avi to video.mp4.

Comment: @furas But shouldn't it affect .avi format also. I can perfectly save as .avi format and play the video. But when I save it as .mp4, I couldn't play it and W and H parameters are also same as the original file.

Comment: `.avi` and `MJPG` are *built into OpenCV*. they **always work**. disregard toyota. -- VideoWriter does not complain if anything is wrong. it simply fails (wrong fourcc, no suitable backend, ...). perhaps check `.isOpened()`. -- support for the mp4 container depends on whether your OpenCV was built with ffmpeg or not. check: `print(cv.getBuildInformation())` -- if you need H.264, you also need to ask for the `avc1` codec.

Comment: if problem is `(W,H)` then it could affect all codecs. But you didn't show minimal working code - so I had no idea if you use the same code for all codecs. In this situations problem is that some formats don't works with some extensions ("containers"). Long time ago I tested different combinations - [main-test-extensions.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/save-file/main-test-extensions.py) and some of them didn't work - but I at least get error messages from program `ffmpeg`  so I could see where is the problem.